# ios - status bar color - iphone landscape issue

Tags: ios, iphone

i tried using this to change the status bar color, works fine in portrait,

```
let proxyViewForStatusBar : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20))     
proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor=UIColor.purpleColor()
self.view.addSubview(proxyViewForStatusBar)
```

And i don't want it in landscape on iphone.

so i tried this

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {


    let proxyViewForStatusBar : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20))



    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue && UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone{

        proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else {
        proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor=UIColor.purpleColor()
    }

    self.view.addSubview(proxyViewForStatusBar)

}
```

but the result is awkward, the status bar shows partially.[image]Attached.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't just add another new proxy view with a clear background, you need to remove the one that is already there.  You should keep a reference to it before you add it as a subview and remove it when the device is in landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have added viewProxy two times. First time it work fines. But when you rotate another view added and last view still here.

So you can create a global for view:

```
 var proxyViewForStatusBar : UIView!
```

In `ViewDidload`:

```
proxyViewForStatusBar= UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20))     
proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor=UIColor.purpleColor()
self.view.addSubview(proxyViewForStatusBar)
```

when rotate:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    proxyViewForStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue && UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone{

        proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else {
        proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor=UIColor.purpleColor()
    }

}
```